# Javascript: Array not shifting, multiple setTimeout functions (JSON)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, animation, settimeout

I'm really stuck on this javascript question!

So I'm making a web page that will be completely animated (so it can be used for display for example in a television). That animation will be configurable by the user (stored in a database).

Right now, I've already made the code to store the configuration and to get the configuration (I do an AJAX call and save the  configuration in an array of json objects) and everything is as it should be.

The problem is in the animation in which I go through the array and use `setTimeout` function to create animations. To iterate through the array I rotate it 
 (I use `array.push(array.shift())` according to the answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41006/rotating-array-members)).

The first time the `intervalmaster` function is used, everything goes according to plan, but when the function is called again I need to rotate the array once more (because of the last animation) and the array just doesn't rotate!

Bellow I've left a portion of the code that I'm using that reproduces the problem I'm getting. I've also added the array `jsonanima` with some possible values (In reality the array is probably much bigger and with higher values).

I really don't understand what is happening, I've also considered that this could be a problem of the multiple `setTimeout` functions because I've read somewhere (couldn't find the link, sorry!) that is not really advised to use multiple `setTimeout`.

If that's the case is there any other way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** Thanks to the comment from [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) I've realized that if change the `console.log(jsonanimate)` to `console.log(JSON.stringfy(jsonanima))` it outputs the correct values (the json array rotated). This got me even more confused! Why do I need to JSON.stringfy to get the array in the correct order?!

Anyway, can't test this with the full code now as I'm not in the office, tomorrow I'll give more feedback. Thank you mplungjan.

**EDIT2:** Finally solved my problem! So the thing was the call to the function recursivegroup (`recursivegroup(0);`), this call was made before I rotated the array, so when restarting the animation the array would still have the incorrect values and every sub-sequential value was wrong.

A special thanks to [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) and [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) for the comments that helped me debug this problem.

Bellow I leave the code corrected so anybody with the same problem can check it out.

```js
jsonanima=[{"VD":5,"A":10,"diff":0.25},{"L":7,"IE":8,"diff":0.25}];
function intervalmaster(flag){
  function recursivegroup(index)
  {
    if(index==0)
    {

        //animateeach(jsonanima,0);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
      //HERE IT WORKS
      jsonanima.push(jsonanima.shift());
      console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonanima));
      //animateeach(jsonanima,0);
       //removed the if statement, since it was irrelevant as mplungjan noted
        recursivegroup(index+1);
    },(jsonanima[0]['diff'])*60*1000);
  }
  //Changed this
  //recursivegroup(0);
  var mastertime=0;
  for(var key in jsonanima)
  {
    mastertime+=(jsonanima[key]['diff']);
  }
  console.log(mastertime,flag);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonanima));
  if(flag==true)
  {
    jsonanima.push(jsonanima.shift());
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonanima));
  }
  //changed to here
  recursivegroup(0);
  masterinterval=setTimeout(function(){intervalmaster(true)},mastertime*60*1000);
}
intervalmaster(false);
```

Comment: 1: Why not use setInterval 2: No need to parseFloat a float 3. Maybe show a JSON.stringify of the content instead of console log it?

Comment: You never leave the recursive part one btw

Comment: I deleted the definition of and call to recursivegroup and it works.

Comment: @mplungjan 1: Well I the reason to use not use setInterval is because I need to execute AJAX calls that may take some time so I only want to trigger the next setTimeout after the AJAX function is called. 2: Corrected in edit (originally the field in json was a string with a float in it). 3: See edit, thank you!

Comment: @James That defeats the entire purpose of the function! I need to use the recursivegroup function and I'm actually convinced that it's working correctly as it outputs what I'm expecting.

Comment: Fair enough.  I saw the two separate timeout functions doing more or less the same and figured you had duplicated the code for testing.

Comment: @mplungjan "You never leave the recursive part one btw", I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. The index is only 0 the first time, notice `recursivegroup(index+1)`...

Comment: Note that the output of `console.log` can be misleading when looking at arrays or objects, since the console will only look up the nested values when you click on the elements in the console, which will not always show you the value as it was at the moment `console.log` executed: those nested values are retrieved asynchronously. This problem will not occur when you do `JSON.stringify`, and log that string (there is nothing nested in a string).

Comment: @trincot Suddenly things are making more a lot more sense! I think I understand now why spent hours debbuging the wrong values. Probably when I was watching the values they had already changed! Can't wait to test it out tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: I meant your statement `jsonanima[0]!=undefined` does not look like it would ever be false

Comment: @mplungjan You are correct! I've found out the solution (see edit). Thank you! :D

Comment: @trincot Thanks to your comment and mplungjan I've fixed the problem (see edit). Thank you!

Comment: Why do you rotate? In a large array that would be quite a processing. Why not just use a counter and reset it when at end?